# XSL for each for an element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to loop an element with data needs to be printed inside the table 
Here is my xml file

```
      <hotels xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='5.xsd'>
<hotel ID="1">
    <Name>Les Jardins du Marais</Name>
    <Stars>3</Stars>
    <Facilities>Internet</Facilities>
    <Address>74 reu Amelot, Paris, 75011</Address>
    <Distance>2</Distance>
    <Available>true</Available>
</hotel>
<hotel ID="2">
    <Name>Golden Tulip Little Palace</Name>
    <Stars>4</Stars>
    <Facilities>Internet</Facilities>
    <Facilities>Gym</Facilities>
    <Facilities>Parking</Facilities>
    <Facilities>Restaurant</Facilities>
    <Address>4 rue salomo,De caus, Paris, 75003</Address>
    <Distance>0.1</Distance>
    <Available>false</Available>
</hotel>
<hotel ID="3">
    <Name>Tilsitt Etoile</Name>
    <Stars>2</Stars>
    <Facilities>Restaurant</Facilities>
    <Address>23 rue brey, Paris, 75017</Address>
    <Distance>3</Distance>
    <Available>false</Available>
</hotel>
<hotel ID="4">
    <Name>Hotel saint charles</Name>
    <Stars>3</Stars>
    <Facilities>Parking</Facilities>
    <Address>6 rue de 1'Esperance, Paris, 75013</Address>
    <Distance>1</Distance>
    <Available>true</Available>
</hotel>
```

Here is my xsl file

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>Students</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">   
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Stars</th>
                    <th>Facilites</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Distance</th>
                    <th>Available</th>    
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="hotels/*">
                    <tr>     
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Stars"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Facilities"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Address"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Distance"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Available"/>
                        </td>    
                    </tr>   
                </xsl:for-each> 
            </table>  
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

As there are multiple facilities for  single hotel i need to find out how to loop that facilities, any help will graet and thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Although you could add a second, nested `xsl:foreach`, it is generally best to maintain Xsl by breaking up the problem into smaller templates, each of which is focussed on a specific concern. It is also preferable to use template matching, rather than an imperative loop to process your xml, as it allows for filtering, recursion and other benefits. In this way, a template can be defined for each `Facility`, and you can then just apply it from your hotel template. You'll also need to determine how you want to show the list of facilities in your table - I've assumed a nested table here:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>Students</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Stars</th>
                        <th>Facilites</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Distance</th>
                        <th>Available</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="hotels/hotel" />
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="hotel">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Stars"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="Facilities" />
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Address"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Distance"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Available"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Facilities">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Xsl Transform fiddle](http://xsltransform.net/)